# Spell checker in British English instead of American English?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I've implemented a spell checker in my MVC web app using some great work from these fine people:

http://jquery-spellchecker.badsyntax.co/

https://github.com/AnthonyTerra/ASP.MVC-Jquery-Spellchecker

However, the spelling in Anthony Terra's project is in American English.  Can anybody advise how to make it British English instead?

Thanks all!

Answer (score 0):

Hunspell is a standardized format. You can find Hunspell dictionaries by doing a google search "hunspell en-gb".

Here is the first result that came up: https://packages.debian.org/sid/hunspell-en-gb

Comment: Thanks.  I grabbed the en_GB dictionary files, created a folder in Anthony's solution called 'en_GB', dumped the files in there and literally did a find/replace on 'en_US' for 'en_GB'.  Compiled the solution and voila!